# Automatically append build date to Eclipse plugin version number

Tags: mercurial, eclipse-plugin, versioning

Many Eclipse plugins have a version number like `1.2.4-201202017`, so the build date (or even the build time) is appended to it.  I wonder how it can be achieved automatically.  I have the version numbers in `feature.xml` file, but I don't want to change it and pollute my version control (mercurial) with all the changes in the build date.  I thought of using keyword expansion, but it requires some special characters that I don't want to be part of the version number.  I build the plugin from within Eclipse so there is no build script to append the date, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do something like this:

I appended .qualifier at the end of every plugin xml (feature.xml...), my plugin version looked like this: 0.9.0.qualifier

If you open your build.properties file, there should be something like this:

```
#Enable / disable the generation of a suffix for the features that use .qualifier. 
#The generated suffix is computed according to the content of the feature   
#generateFeatureVersionSuffix=true
```

uncomment that, build and hopefully it will work.

Comment: This works very well with Kepler too but the `generateFeatureVersionSuffix` line was not in my build.properties file. (I updated an EMF plugin). Simply adding it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get date (in OS) in needed format YYYYMMDD, you can build own keyword for Keywords extension and use it (system command *are callable* inside keyword definition)

Comment: The mercurial keyword approach was just a desperate idea. The other answer provided the eclipse-way I was looking for -- maybe not quite clearly formulated in my question.